# PuTTY or MobaTerm: autologin to a Linux server that has 2 IDs to authentication with

Tags: linux, login, remote-access

Is there to login to a Linux server application via PuTTY or MobaTerm automatically wherein the first login is the Linux User account and the next login is the Application account?

The login IDs are NOT the same.

Comment: You mean a script of some sort that contains the credentials for and logs into the user session on the OS, and then does the same for an application? What application?

Answer (score 0):

You can use macro execution feature on MobaXterm.

Create a new session via the menu bar (Sessions --> New Session) and A window will open up.

Select SSH tab, go to "Advanced SSH settings" and select `<custom macro>` at "Execute macro at session start(experimental)" combo box.

[image: MobaXterm Session settings window]

Answer (score -1):

Check this solution where step by step instructions are detailed on how to use custom macros - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48019517

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon here. Sites disappear with the content they hold. You should post pertinent parts of the answer here. That way if the link goes away, the content stays.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1224175)